# Kafka Connect S3 - get the header from the message

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

use-case : Consume the messages sent to a topic and store in AWS S3

im using Kafka-s3-connector to achieve this , its working perfectly fine but

Each file is encoded as

```
topic_kafkaPartition_startOffset.format
```

Instead i want to encode header of the message as the file name while storing in s3.

Comment: Which Kafka / Connect version are you using?

Comment: What you're asking for isn't possible without at least writing your own Kafka Connect Partitioner class, by the way

Comment: @cricket_007  i'm using the **confluent kafka**, and **Kakfa-S3-connect** , is there any way we could do using properties file instead of writing kafka connect partition-er class. Thanks

Comment: "Confluent Kafka" is not really a thing, It's just Apache Kafka. Which **version** of Kafka Connect are you using? I understand you are using the S3 Connect, and I am saying your must write custom code to overwrite these methods. https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-storage-cloud/blob/master/kafka-connect-s3/src/main/java/io/confluent/connect/s3/TopicPartitionWriter.java#L473-L488